# Move count() outside of foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, count, laravel

I have a list of arrays which I need to apply some logic to, each element in the array refers to a category in my database.

So far I'm counting how many times the category has applied in my database using a count within a foreach loop. Is there any way to move this count outside of my foreach loop? So far it's not really running slow at all, benchmarked it at 0.00241899490356.

But I have way over 150 categories, each being looped through and counted 6 times. I fear that with increase in category usage and database space it'll just become sluggish. I read that DB actions shouldn't be in loops. Is this alright and forgivable practice in similar scenarios?

edit :: I really apologise for my lack of code. I usually outline the question first, then fill in the holes. My time ran out. Not an excuse for getting sloppy but it's the one I have. I'll fix now, before reading the current replies.

```
    $nazioni = array(
        'ad' => array( 'eur', ),
        'ae' => array( 'asi', ),
        'af' => array( 'asi', ),
        'ag' => array( 'nam', ),
        'al' => array( 'eur', ),
        'am' => array( 'asi', 'eur', ),
        ...
        'za' => array( 'afr', ),
        'zm' => array( 'afr', ),
        'zw' => array( 'afr', ),
    );

    $categorie = array(
        'eur',
        'asi',
        'afr',
        'nam',
        'sam',
        'oce',
    );

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($categorie as $cat)
    {
        echo '<li><a href="#">'.$cat.'</a></li>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($nazioni as $n=>$c)
        {
            if(array_intersect(array($cat), $c) == true)
            {
                echo Filtra::uri_locale($n, $cat, $uri);
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

The counting is done in my Filtra::uri_locale action.

```
public static function uri_locale ($n, $cat, $uri)
{
    $count = DB::table('recipes')
    ->where(function($query)
    {
        $corso = Filtra::corso(explode("/", URI::current()));
        if(!empty($corso))
        {
            $query->where_in('course', $corso, 'OR');
        }
    })
    ->where('nation', '=', $n)->count();

    //if more than 0, or not empty and in the uri array.
    if($count > 0 || !empty($uri) && array_intersect(array($n), $uri))
    {
        return self::uri_href($uri, $n, $count);
        // ex: returns a link named Italy (3) if Italy has 3 results counted.
    }
}
```

My relevant database tables that I'm looking up:

```
| id | title | nation | course |
————————————————————————————————
| 1  | Pizza | it     | 4      |
```

It is translated to Italy, course is used for another layer of categorising which uses a similar logic, same solution to the same problem.

Again, really sorry about this mixup, I'm way over my head and deadline.

Comment: u should probably include some code

Comment: it's hard to imagine question like this. please add some code.

Comment: You can count how many value are in an array by using array_count_values();

Comment: `$i = count($arr)` right before `foreach()`?

Comment: You can do logic in DB queries.. Show us the code maybe it is possible to adapt it

Comment: The database schema you are using, and the code that you are using, would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't given any information on your PHP code or database, Let me make few assumption and answer. Let's assume that 1, hello, world are your categories.

You can optimize this in 2 ways.

**Method 1**

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

O/P

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

**Method 2**

You can use database function `COUNT()` for this.

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) FROM category_table GROUP BY category;
```

O/P

```
+--------+----------+
|category| COUNT(*) |
+--------+----------+
| 1      |        2 |
| hello  |        2 |
| world  |        1 |
+--------+----------+
```

If you have any issue let me know

Comment: Group_by did it. Thank you so so much for taking the time to answer, and once again I apologise so much for not including code in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to let MySQL do the Counting, have a look at this here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html then you won't have to "transfer" all the data to PHP and do the Count there.

Comment: The 'GROUP BY' argument appears to be my solution, I'll run a few tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some variables that stores the count for each category. then you test if the variable is not null you take the value in it otherwise you do the count.